# Corelocation automatically drops pin when Current Location is found

Tags: iphone, mkmapview, core-location

I am making a map view with CoreLocation.
the problem I'm facing right now is that whenever I found a location.
It sometimes pops back to my current Location.
i haven't tested this bug thoroughly but is it possible to turn this off?
so I can add the pin myself?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This keeps us motivated to give answers

Answer (score 2):

If you are adding mapview via XIB then in the map view properties panel uncheck the

> Shows User Location

or if you are adding it programmatically then do

```
[mapView setShowsUserLocation:NO];
```

But then you have to find the location yourself and then add the pin.